# Set default value to a row with eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have created a resource controller using laravel with post and get method:

```
class MyController extends Controller{
    //get method when page is visited
    public function index()
    {
        $data=array(
            'title'=>'Standard Stock',
            'standards'=>DB::table('standards')
            ->join('ps_product_lang','ps_product_lang.id_product','=','standards.id_product')
            ->select('standards.*','ps_product_lang.name')
            ->get()
        );
        return view('pages.standards')->with($data);
    }

    //post method to update value

     public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {

   $this->validate($request,[
        'quantity'=>'required'
    ]);
    $standard=Standard::find($id);
    $standard->quantity=$request->input('quantity');
    $standard->save();
    return redirect('/standards')->with('success','Quantity Updated');
    }
}
```

it works fine by now, but the problem is i have 2000 product in my ps_product_lang database, i want to set the all the `$standard->quantity` to 15 for each of them. 
I used to update the quantity value via the `update()` function in the controller.

But now I want to set an initial value as 15 to all the `$standard->quantity` and i am definitely not gonna click 2000 time form button to submit the post requests.

My question is: is there any convenient way to set all `$standard->quantity` value to 15? without touching other code?

Comment: `DB::statement('update standards set quantity=15');`

Comment: @rkj thanks for your response, sorry i am new to laravel, just wondering where should i insert this raw SQL? is it supposed within the index() function?

Comment: i think it should be run only once, so put it in your index and run that index route once and then remove the code

Comment: if you wan to update through update method then put there but then it will update all your 2000 records with the in put value

Comment: @rkj just above the $data=arra() right?

Comment: do you wan to execute it only once or it should update with whatever the value you will have in `$request->input('quantity');` ?

Comment: just only update once

Comment: then put it inside index before `$data=array` and execute that action once and then remove the code

Answer (score 2):

There are several options.

**1) SQL Update**

You can update the database with a SQL query and set all rows to quantity = 15

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang SET quantity = 15
```

**2) Laravel Jobs**

You could create a job for doing this.

See here in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#creating-jobs

**3) Migrations**

You can use a migration for this and set a default value for this column.

```
Schema::table('ps_product_lang ', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('quantity')->default('15')->change();
        });
```

See migration details on the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. You have to edit your create_table_file on "database/migrations" folder.

So just give a default value for the column as '15'.

for example:

```
Schema::create('platforms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('platform_id');
            $table->string('quantity')->default(15);
            $table->string('price')->default('');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Once you done, you have to rollback your table.

This will remove all of your data, so take a backup of your table first.

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Or you can create a new migration and change existing column.

Comment: I agree with @Stranger . Dont modify existing migrations, make new ones. I have had issues in the past with caching that laravel does.